# how to call async function in response

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I need to use `await` in a response function, but I couldn't figure out how. 
(Note: `func2()` is an async function)

```
async function get_data() { 
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // http request, returns json...
    await func1(data1, data2).then(json => {   
      if (json.value < 100) {
        await func2(); //error => await is only valid in async function
      }  
    }) 
  }
}
```

I have to wait for `func2`, how can I do that?

I tried this:

```
async function get_data() { 
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await func1(data1, data2).then(json =>
      async function() { // nothing happens, function doesnt work.
        if (json.value < 100) {
          await func2();   
        }  
      }) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally easier if you don't mix `await` and `.then()`.  Since you want to sequence two operations and it appears you want the `for` loop to be sequenced too, it's simpler with just `await`.

```
async function get_data() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let json = await func1(data1, data2);
    if (json.value < 100) {
      await func2();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i have been struggle to solve this for one day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of `.then()` and use `await` instead.

`await` `func1` and get the `value` and then check if the `value` satisfies the condition and if it does `await` `func2`.

Check the demo snippet below:

```js
async function get_data() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const { value } = await func1("Hello", "World");
    if (value < 100) {
      console.log(await func2(value));
    }
  }
  console.log("END!")
}

const func1 = (d1, d2) =>
  new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res({ value: Math.random(0) * 200 }), 200));

const func2 = (v) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(v), 200));

get_data();
```